# Should Values of "x" at Which A Power Series Conditionally Converges Be Included in the Interval of Convergence?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

Take, for example, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n}$. When we apply the ratio test, we get |x| < 1, meaning our possible endpoints are -1 and 1. When we test x = 1, we see by the p-series that the series diverges, but when we test x = -1, we get conditional convergence (because the series converges under the alternating series test, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$| = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$, so the series doesn't converge absolutely).
My question is: should we then say that the interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n}$ is (-1, 1), or [-1, 1)?

Comment: It converges on $[-1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

"Conditional" vs "absolute" convergence are subcategories; either one still counts as a convergent series. In your example, the conditionally converging endpoint is part of the interval of convergence, so the correct IoC is $[-1, 1)$.

The conditional vs absolute terminology is useful because it changes what techniques you'd use for working with the series. For example, if the series is absolutely convergent then you can rearrange the terms in the most convenient order, but if it's only conditionally convergent then rearranging the terms could change the sum or even produce a divergent series (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)).